# Java byterray to string must be equal python bytearray string when generate secret with SecretKeyFactory

Tags: java, python, character-encoding, cryptography, pbkdf2

I have a task to rewrite some python crypto code to java. I'm new in python. Python code:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
backend = default_backend()  



PASSWORD = bytes((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16))

key = PBKDF2HMAC(hashes.SHA256(), 32, salt, iterations, backend).derive(PASSWORD)
```

My java implementation:

```
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
    import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
     byte[] PASSWORD = new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(new String(PASSWORD).toCharArray(), salt, iterations, 256));
    byte[] key = tmp.getEncoded();
```

As you can see PASSWORD is a byte array which I get from a hex string, i.e 010203....0F10, I can't change it (i.e. can't specify it as a string in python realization, as I understand server transforms PASSWORD to byte array also). All worked fine with this dummy PASSWORD i.e. keys generated by python and java code were equal. But I'm faced with a problem when the password changed to arbitrary, i.e. for example AFFFFFFFFDBGEHTH....
As I understand the problem with java byte array representation as signed integers. I.e. when I convert hex "FFFAAABBBCCCDDDDFFAAAAAAAAAAAABB" for example to byte array it will be byte array [-1, -6, -86, -69, -68, -52, -35, -35, -1, -86, -86, -86, -86, -86, -86, -69], but in python it will [255, 250, 170, 187, 188, 204, 221, 221, 255, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 187]. Then when I convert java byte array to charArray for PBEKeySpec constructor - new PBEKeySpec(new String(new byte[]{-1, -6, -86, -69, -68, -52, -35, -35, -1, -86, -86, -86, -86, -86, -86, -69}).toCharArray()... it works as unexpected.

How I have to change my java code to receive the same key as in python? As I understand  I have to encode java byte array string to the same value as in python .derive(...) method.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
salt       = b'salt'
PASSWORD = = bytes((255, 250, 170, 187, 188, 204, 221, 221, 255, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 187))
key = PBKDF2HMAC(hashes.SHA256(), 32, salt, 512, backend).derive(PASSWORD)
```

and

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
password = new String(new byte[]{-1, -6, -86, -69, -68, -52, -35, -35, -1, -86, -86, -86, -86, -86, -86, -69});
var key = secretKeyFactory
                    .generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), 
"salt".getBytes(), 512, 256))
                    .getEncoded();
```

should give the same result. It works for new byte[]{1,2,3,4,....16} password.

UPDATE2: I changed password to unsigned int[] but it not works anyway:

```
    char[] password = new char[PASSWORD.length];
            for (int i = 0; i<PASSWORD.length; password[i] = (char)(PASSWORD[i++] & 0xFF));
    var key = secretKeyFactory
                    .generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password, "salt".getBytes(), 512, 256))
                    .getEncoded();
```

Comment: `-1` and `255` are the same byte value `011111111b`. The first is the signed interpretation (2's complement), the second is the unsigned interpretation. It all depends on how you (the human usually) wish to interpret it. The computer won't get confused.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But as I see from the experiment java and python realizations are different. When I start to work with bytes greater than 127 I get unexpected results.

Comment: Then show the code where you get unexpected results.

Comment: Do not print byte array as values. Instead use a standardized method like hex encoding or base64 encoding then you can compare them even between different programming languages/run-times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the different digests (s. 1st [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63903032)), the problem is that the key derived with `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256` is an instance of `PBKDF2KeyImpl`, which requires a string as password. This string is UTF8 encoded in `PBKDF2KeyImpl` (see documentation of the class [`PBKDF2KeyImpl`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/java.base/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/PBKDF2KeyImpl.java)). Here, however, the password is an (arbitrary) byte sequence, which is generally not compatible with UTF8, so that the data is corrupted during UTF8 decoding. A possible solution is to replace `PBEKeySpec` with BouncyCastle's `PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator`, which expects the password as byte array (in `init`):

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.PBEParametersGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.SHA256Digest;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
...
byte[] salt = "salt".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
int iterations = 512;
byte[] PASSWORD = new byte[] { (byte)255, (byte)250, (byte)170, (byte)187, (byte)188, (byte)204, (byte)221, (byte)221, (byte)255, (byte)170, (byte)170, (byte)170, (byte)170, (byte)170, (byte)170, (byte)187 };
PBEParametersGenerator generator = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator(new SHA256Digest());
generator.init(PASSWORD, salt, iterations);
byte[] keyBytes = ((KeyParameter)generator.generateDerivedParameters(256)).getKey(); 
// with bytesToHex from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338
System.out.println(bytesToHex(keyBytes).toLowerCase());  // d8aa4772e9648572611fe6dca7f653353de934cdb3b29fab94eb13ba2b198b9f
```

The result now matches that of the Python code:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes

salt = b'salt'
iterations = 512
PASSWORD = bytes((255, 250, 170, 187, 188, 204, 221, 221, 255, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 187))
key = PBKDF2HMAC(hashes.SHA256(), 32, salt, iterations).derive(PASSWORD)

print(key.hex()) # d8aa4772e9648572611fe6dca7f653353de934cdb3b29fab94eb13ba2b198b9f
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works. I changed to SHA256Digest() for my situation.

Comment: @ValeriyK.- You're welcome. Yes, SHA256 is more consistent, I've updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `SHA1` in your Java code and `SHA256` in your Python code, which is why you're getting different results. Use `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256`.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I added old code. Now I'm using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 and it still doesn't work. I fixed.